# Dependable select box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code :

```
<form id="frmKat" role="form" action="" method="post">
    Country :
    <select name="country" id="country">
      <option>-select your country-</option>
    <?php 
    $result=mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * from regios");
    while($country=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){         
    echo "<option value=$country[id]>$country[naam]</option>";

    } ?>
    </select>

    City :
    <select name="city" id="city">
        <option>-select your city-</option>
    </select>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-success" name="btnConvert" id="btnConvert">Convert</button>
</form>
```

My ajax code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){


           $("#country").change(function(){
                 var country=$("#country").val();
                 $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"getcutoff.php",
                    data:"country="+country,
                    success:function(data){
                          $("#city").html(data);
                    }
                 });
           });
       });
  </script>
```

And my getcutoff.php file is next :

```
 <?php
session_start();
include("config.php");
global $kon;
ob_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["admin"])){ 

  $country=$_POST["country"];

  $result=mysqli_query($kon, "select * FROM cutoffs WHERE regio_id=". $country ." ");
  while($city=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value=$city[id]>$city[datetime]</option>";

  }
}else{
    ob_flush();
    die("Salut");   
}
?>
```

I'm trying to make dependable selectboxes. When user chooses something in the first selected box, then they will be taken to the second one where they can choose values which are connected to the first selected box. In first box I get values, but when I choose something in the second one, I get nothing. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I do not get any error, I just don't get anything in the second select box when i choose something in the first one.

Comment: That is what i want to know. Open the network tab and see if the request is made when you apply a change event on country dropdown.

Comment: @Boky in ajax code, try like this `var country=$(this).val();`

Comment: @Shehary It works now. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Group your options in a php variable as string and use a single echo in getcutoff.php

```
$res ='';
while($city=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ $res.="<option value=$city[id]>$city[datetime]</option>"; } 
echo $res;
```

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is the same. Nothing happends in the second select box when I choose something in the first one.

Comment: Can you log the data of ajax success to the console so that we can check it the response

Comment: It seems that the problem was in the ajax, I've changed one line to `var country=$(this).val();`  like @Shehary said and now it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

your echo looks a bit wrong. Also, I assume you have saved your daetime as DateTime in SQL, thus you'd need to convert it before defining it as a string.

```
$date = strtotime($city[datetime]);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

echo "<option value='".$city[id].">".$date."'>My Option</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes datetime is DateTime in sql. I tried your code but the problem is the same.

Comment: Mate you really need to specify your error with more details :( Otherwise we can't help you much!

Comment: It seems that the problem was in the ajax, I've changed one line to `var country=$(this).val();` like @Shehary said and now it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ah I'm glad it's solved. So now you can get your option value corrected as well, as mentioned above! :) all the bests.

Comment: I get correct option value with  `$city["datetime"]`

Comment: ah great then, I primarily thought that could be the cause of it :)